# Avenues for overcomming FFT bottleneck?

Tags: matlab, optimization, fft

I spent some time optimizing my algorithm and my quasi-serial (no explicit parralelization) code spends 95% of the time on a line that performs the `fftn` and dense single(float) matrix multiplication

```
for k=1:10
    q = q +  x{k}.* fftn( mArray{k}.* ifftn( mOther{k} .* z ) );
```

I tried adding some wisdoms for the FFT although the performance increase was negligible.

I am at a loss for ways to speed up this code, do you think compiling FFTW could result in a performance increase? I am using Matlab 2012b for a 3rd generation i7.

**Edit**

I seem to have made a typo, x depends on k, it would have been too easy otherwise. I was hoping somebody could speak to optimizing the actual fft.

```
    q = q +  x.* fftn( mArray{k}.* ifftn( mOther{k} .* z ) );
    q = q +  x{k}.* fftn( mArray{k}.* ifftn( mOther{k} .* z ) );
```

Comment: As you mention parallel, how about using parfor and storing to a variable like q(k), you can add them afterwards.

Comment: When I use the parfor I get worse throughput, and I suspect that the fftn command is automatically parallelized in the latest matlab versions. I want to make sure my serial version is optimal before moving on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the q's together before fftn transforming and multiplying by x. e.g.

```
A = 0;
for k=1:10
     A = A + mArray{k}.* ifftn( mOther{k} .* z );
end
q = q + x.*fftn(A);
```

IMO this should be equivalent.

Comment: This is a perfectly good suggestion, but I seem to have made a typo when entering in my line! I have edited it, sorry.

Comment: Well, that changes the situation of course. Sorry I dont see any way to speed up your code without knowing what it is supposed do. Also MATLAB already uses the FFTW package for its fft routines. See the fftw function (It allows some fine tuning of the fftn routine - maybe that helps). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using convolutions instead of back and forth FFTs?

Comment: No, I haven't quite thought about. Maybe I misunderstood, but isn't the FFT a more efficient than a convolution (convolution implemented via FFT?).

Comment: In general you are correct, but you are doing FFT back and forth and multiply. My Fourier is a bit rusty, but I think it's worth while looking at the math, taking advantage of linearity of FFT, and the convolution theorem might give you some leverage...